# Temporary directory when users group has access to write and modify data in w7

Tags: windows-7

I'm searching for temporary directory in W7 where all users can read / write / append / modify etc. data. User should be able to modify files created by other user. I though that Windows\temp is such a directory by my W7 activate UAC window and ask for approval when I try to open it. Is there some other location that can be use to share data among users ?

Comment: I found it, there is C:\Users\Public with all directories, accessible for all users

Answer (score 1):

Create a new directory, set permissions, done.

Answer (score 0):

The directory `windows\temp` is not a public directory.
The proper place now to store temp information is within the users profile in their personal temp directory. (If you type `set` at a command prompt you can see the path in one of the environment variables)

Obviously you can't share that between users. So mailq's answer is best. Create a new folder and set permissions on it for everyone.